# global transformation in sed between two tokens

Tags: regex, sed

My problem seems to be simple but I found it suprisingly difficult to convert into sed expression.

I need to 'underscorize' names between certain tokens in a file. So if the line has tokens `:` and `=` I need to convert 'multi word name' into 'multi_word_name' between these two tokens.

I know it is fairly easy to do two step match anything between the tokens and then global replace spaces with underscores but I can't find a way of retaining unmatched part of line for writing back into file.

Comment: Can the line contain more than one pair of `:` and `=` tokens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed, tr and bash):

```
sed 's/:[^=]*=/$(tr " " "_" <<<"&")/g;s/.*/echo "&"/e' file
```

or just using sed:

```
sed ':a;/:[^_=]*=/!b;s//\n&\n/;h;s/.*\n\(.*\)\n.*/\1/;y/ /_/;H;g;s/\n.*\n\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2\1/;ta' file
```

Comment: "just" using sed

Answer (score 2):

You could do it with two invocations of `sed`:

```
echo 'pre with space :multi word name=post with space' \
| sed 's/[:=]/\n&/g' | sed '/^:/s/ /_/g' | tr -d '\n'
```

To make this work on a file, you would do something like this (in bash):

```
while read; do 
  echo "$REPLY" | sed 's/[:=]/\n&/g' | sed '/^:/s/ /_/g' | tr -d '\n'
  echo
done < infile
```

Although `awk` would be a more suitable tool for the task:

```
awk -F '[:=]' '{ gsub(" ", "_", $2); print $1 ":" $2 "=" $3 }' infile
```